# Java multiple connection downloading

Tags: java, download, httpurlconnection

I wanted to get some advice, I have started on a new project to create a java download accelerator that will use multiple connections. I wanted to know how best to go about this.

So far I have figured out that i can use HttpUrlConnection and use the range property, but wanted to know an efficient way of doing this. Once i have download the parts from the multiple connections i will then have to join the parts so that we end up with a fully downloaded file.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your question is not terribly clear or specific. Could you possibly clarify. Thanks

Comment: @ all: **Questions need votes too!**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Get the **content length** of the file to download.
2. **Divide** it according to a criteria (size, speed, …).
3. Run multiple threads to download the file starting at different positions,
   and save them in different files: `myfile.part1`,  `myfile.part2`, …
4. Once downloaded, join the parts into **one single file**.

I tried the following code to get the content length:

```
public Downloader(String path) throws IOException {
    int len = 0;
    URL url = new URL(path);
    URLConnection connectUrl = url.openConnection();
    System.out.println(len = connectUrl.getContentLength());
    System.out.println(connectUrl.getContentType());

    InputStream input = connectUrl.getInputStream();
    int i = len;
    int c = 0;
    System.out.println("=== Content ==="); 
    while (((c = input.read()) != -1) && (--i > 0)) {
        System.out.print((char) c);
    }
    input.close(); 
}
```

Here's a sample code to join the files:

```
public void join(String FilePath) {
    long leninfile=0, leng=0;
    int count=1, data=0;
    try {
        File filename = new File(FilePath);
        RandomAccessFile outfile = new RandomAccessFile(filename,"rw");
        while(true) {
            filename = new File(FilePath + count + ".sp");
            if (filename.exists()) {
                RandomAccessFile infile = new RandomAccessFile(filename,"r");
                data=infile.read();
                while(data != -1) {
                    outfile.write(data);
                    data=infile.read();
                }
                leng++;
                infile.close();
                count++;
            } else break;
        }
        outfile.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Shaaf i think that is just what i was looking for, will give it a bash :)

Comment: I am failing to see in your sample method `Downloader` (horrible to use a method name starting with upper-case character, BTW) how you do the multi-stream downloading. I would have expected to see you spawning multiple threads, starting downloads at different offsets etc. I wonder why this answer was even accepted, because other than theoretically, it does not address the question of multi-stream downloading.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to avoid joining segments after downloading you could use a [`FileChannel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html).
With a [`FileChannel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html), you can write to any position of a file (even with multiple threads).

So you could first *allocate* the whole file, and then
write the segments where they belong *as they come in*.

See the [Javadocs page](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) for more info.

Comment: +1: I think `FileChannel` is the most efficient/easy way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

[JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/download/index) is the best downloader I've seen. If you are interested, it's open source and surely you can learn a lot from their code.

Comment: `...surely you can learn a lot from their code...` not _only_ that, you can even **modify** it or **use** it on your own program. (it's open-source!)