# How to merge binary files using Java?

Tags: java, file, merge

I am downloading file parts using socket, saving them as .part1, .part2 etc.( However I am not sure if I should). I am trying to merge them in a .bin file. Can any of you recommend me a way to do that? Should I read them all as binary and then append it? I don't even know if that makes sense actually.

Comment: I tried this one but I didn't understand this code. Can it help me??  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243073/java-multiple-connection-downloading/2243731#2243731

Comment: Cut & paste it and try.   It's unlikely that anyone will improve on that.  If you can't understand it, perhaps the problem is beyond you.

Comment: Well, I found out that it is not beyond me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you open the first part for input, and open an output streamof the form

```
out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFile)));
```

then read in your first part file as bytes, and use the writeByte() method to write it all out.

Then close the first part, open the second part, and read it in, then out to the output file.

Will that not merge the contents of the two files?

Comment: This works.  Remember (unlike what Ada apparently did, as referenced by his own answer) that you should only read in one file at a time then append that to the output unless you're sure the entire output file can fit in your Java heap.

Comment: I only modified the code I gave reference to. But it is kinda slow. readByte and writeByte would be faster? Btw who is "he"?

Answer (score 0):

I did it. Read files one by one and wrote them to output.