# Efficiently develop media app

Tags: android, performance, android-mediaplayer

I am developing an app in which I am trying to play a large download.This file is broken into small chunks of data and downloaded on the device, and from there I am trying to play them.

I am having few doubts in the development of this app

1. Can *.mp3 be added to create a new *.mp3 on the device itself.
2. As in my current case, I have not figured out solution for question 1, I am playing a file one after the other. What is the
   best way/approach to map these files with a progressbar/seekbar.

Any other approach seeking maximum  efficiency of the app and efficient use of resources also welcome.

Comment: If the file is broken down into chunks, is it not possible to re-assemble them on the client end?

Comment: if that is the thing, please can you guide me...

Comment: While I am not immediately failure with the process, the following links should be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431945/split-and-join-back-a-binary-file-in-java  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532462/how-to-merge-binary-files-using-java

Comment: Is it possible to simply reverse the method in which you used to split the file?

Comment: @gh123man The files are basically downloaded from web ( zedge.net), just like ringtones

Comment: If I understand the MP3 format correctly, (Someone please correct me if I'm wrong!) they can be directly streamed into one another. As in, you can concatenate the binary files, and they will still work as one.

Comment: @gh123man thank you for the hint ;) will try approach commented ;)

Comment: I believe the only thing you would normally need to watch out for when concatenating mp3's is that all files have the same bit rate, but for this purpose you should be able to concatenate the binary files and produce the desired result.